# looping through an IList and missing last member of list

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, .net-4.5

I have this method below that loops through an IList to create annual conferences.

The loop *does* work except it ***always*** skips the last conference in the IList.

I can't figure out why it's doing it.

I've tried various fixes, but they always end up creating an endless loop.

I think I just need another pair of eyes to take a look at it.

I've left out a few of the gritty details, but the main structure of the loop is there.

Thanks!

```
public static IEnumerable<YearEvents> AnnualConferences(IList<conference> conferences)
    {
        //if list is empty, get out
        if (conferences.Count == 0)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        var position = 0;
        var confExists = GetConf();

        while (position < conferences.Count)
        {
            if (confExists)
            {
                CreateConferenceTitle(conferences[position].Title);
                position++;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return
                    conferences[position].CreateConference();
                break;
            }
        }

        position = position % conferences.Count;

        var stopPos = conferences.Count - 1;

        do
        {
            var startPos = position;
            var nextPos = (position + 1) % conferences.Count;

            while (nextPos != stopPos)
            {
                CreateConferenceTitle(conferences[position].Title);
                position = nextPos;
                nextPos = (position + 1) % conferences.Count;
            }

            yield return
                conferences[position].CreateConference();
            position = nextPos;

        } while (position != stopPos);   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning new value of `position` after `yield return`.

```
yield return conferences[position].CreateConference();
position = nextPos;
```

This line

```
position = nextPos;
```

it's not even called. Try moving it before `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

try to check

```
var stopPos = conferences.Count - 1;
```

change to

```
var stopPos = conferences.Count;
```

and

```
while (position < conferences.Count)
```

change to

```
while (position <= conferences.Count)
```

Comment: thanks.  I did try that and it goes into an infinite loop because nextPos eventually gets reset back to 0 at the very end and the whole process repeats itself.